# How to retain/reassing the factor levels for a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, csv, machine-learning, dataframe

I have large dataset that I am using to train a machine learning algorithm in R. After all the data preprocessing, I have a dataframe that contains factors and numeric values. I split such dataset into a training set and a test set, and save them to file with write.csv().

When I read back the test.csv and train.csv files it may happen that some of the factors have lost levels. This makes some of the algorithms fail when creating design matrices.

Here is a detailed example. Assume that originally I had a dataset with 12 rows that I split into a training set of 8 rows and a test set of 4 rows. I save the 8 training rows to train.csv and the 4 rows to test.csv. Note that *factor2* has levels (a,b,c,d) in train.csv:

```
  factor1 factor2 value
1       1       a     1
2       2       b     0
3       3       c     1
4       4       d     1
5       2       a     0
6       4       c     1
7       3       b     0
8       1       a     1
```

but only (a,b,c) in test.csv:

```
  factor1 factor2
1       4       a
2       2       b
3       4       c
4       1       a
```

And same for *factor1*, level 3 is missing in the test set.
When I read back the file test.csv, R assumes that *factor1* has levels (1,2,4) and *factor2* has levels (a,b,c). I would like to find a way to tell R the actual levels.

The solution that I thought is to save the levels at the beginning, from the original dataset with 12 points and then reassign them after reading train.csv and test.csv.

I would like to avoid using the save() method from R, because the datasets that I am creating may go to other languages/packages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, subsetting should keep all factor levels in a vector. Here let's imagine a is our data, column a is our categorical variable, and b is our response:

```
a <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
z <- a[1:2, ]
z$a

[1] a b
Levels: a b c
```

If you are losing factors in your sub-setting to train and test sets, you need a better way of sub-setting.

If your problem is writing a .csv, you probably want to reinclude them as an NA in the response column. You can do this a ton of ways - here's a merge:

```
merge(data.frame(a = levels(z$a)), z, all=TRUE)

  a  b
1 a  1
2 b  2
3 c NA
```

Edit: From your example, using the first data as `dat` and the second as `dat2`:

```
levels(dat2$factor1) <- levels(dat$factor1)
levels(dat2$factor2) <- levels(dat$factor2)
```

would be the easiest way.

Comment: I would say that "losing" a factor value in the test set is ok. No need of other sub-setting. I train with ("a", "b", "c") but I only test cases ("b", "c"). Perfectly fine in my opinion. Regarding the merge, can you do it with multiple factors? I have multiple factor features with "missing" values

Comment: you should take a look at the functions `expand` and `complete` from the package `tidyr`. Stick a representative part of your data in the question for a more specific example.

Comment: I expanded the question with a more detailed explanation and a toy example that has the same problem that my dataset has.